# Find the code that added a specific service to IServiceCollection

Tags: .net

I didn't register [TimeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeprovider?view=net-8.0) myself, yet I could use it injected in a service of mine. So I debugged `builder.Services` in Program.cs, and found out that it had been added:

[image]

Is it possible to find the code that added a specific service to `IServiceCollection`? I guess an external library does it.